# name validation with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a name field in `javascript` with the following rules:

- Names are between 5 and 15 characters.
- Letters might be capital or small letters.
- Names must start and end with letters.
- Spaces are allowed but not numbers.

I have tried the following regular expression but I want to make sure whether it is correct or not.
`re = /^[a-z][a-z\s]{3,14}[a-z]$/i;`

Comment: Your regex allows 16 character names.

Comment: Can a character mean a space too?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I just edited it now. I realized that and edited it.

Comment: Also, your regex allows tab, or other whitespace characters covered by `\s`. If you specifically mean space, just put a space.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, any other comments are appreciated.
Thanks,, ^_^

Comment: @MagedSaeed You seem to have glossed over my comment. Are spaces considered valid characters for your code?

Comment: As I see it it still can contain 16 characters (1 + 14 + 1). The middle expression should be `{3,13}`

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder yes, they are. It is the fourth rule in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(?=.{5,15}$)[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)*$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6I3qq3/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{5,15}$)` - a positive lookahead that only checks if, from the start of string, and up to the end of string, there are any 5 to 15 chars other than line break chars (this is a non-consuming pattern, the regex index is at the start of the string when the pattern is matched)
- `[a-z]+` - (start of the consuming pattern) 1 or more ASCII letters
- `(?:\s+[a-z]+)*` - 0+ repetitions of

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `[a-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /^(?=.{5,15}$)[a-z]+(?: +[a-z]+)*$/i;
var strs = ["abcde abcde abc","abcde abcde","abcde abcdeabcde","abcde abcd1","abcdeabcde"];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s,"=>",rx.test(s));
}
```